# Count including 0 on join two tables with different rows postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have two tables, users table that contains all the users in my system and other table called action with all the actions done by the users in my system, what I want to get is a query where i can count the actions by the user and if I don't have any action for one user get 0.

My two tables:

```
Users Table:

Name       Place
----------------------
James      Supermarket
Alex       Bank 
Ignatius   BookShop

Action table:

Name   Action
--------------------
James  Buy
James  Buy
Alex   Complaint
Alex   Buy
Alex   Buy
```

I want something like this:

```
Name       Transactions   Place
-------------------------------
James      2              Supermarket
Alex       3              Bank
Ignatius   0              BookShop
```

I tryied with:

```
SELECT users.name, 
   (SELECT Count(action.name) 
    FROM   action, 
           users 
    WHERE  action.name = users.name 
    GROUP  BY action.name) 
    users.place
FROM 
action, 
users 
WHERE  action.name = users.name
```

But is always giving me this error:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
>   SQL state: 21000

Any idea about how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  That said, you don't need any joins at all for this query, if you want to use correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT u.name, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM action a 
        WHERE a.name = u.name 
       ) as cnt,
       u.place
FROM users u;
```

For performance, you want an index on `action(name)`.  With such an index, this may be faster than alternative versions using `left join` and `group by`.

Notes:

- All the tables have table aliases, which are abbreviations for the table name.
- No joins are needed for this version of the query.
- No `group by` in the subquery.
- No `where` clause is needed in the outer query.

Comment: Your solution works fine, slower, but it's good. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You should do a left join first, then apply group by to its result:

```
SELECT
    u.name
,   COUNT(a.name) AS Transactions
,   u.place
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN action a ON a.name = u.name 
GROUP BY u.name, u.place
```

Left join ensures that a user record is not discarded even if it does not have associated transactions in the `action` table.

Comment: hi, @dasblinkenlight it's working fine but I do not want include u.place in the group by, when I remove it is givinig me the error that say I have to include, I cannot include. How could I do it?

Comment: @JoanTriay Assuming that `name` uniquely identifies a user, it makes no difference that you use `place` in `group by`, because both fields come from the same table, and one of the fields (name) uniquely identifies the row.

Answer (score 1):

As with previous answer a left join would see you through.
If you want to include place in the results then do the left join after summarising

```
SELECT a.name,
        ISNULL(b.cnt, 0) AS Transactions,
        a.place
FROM users a
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT name,
            Count(name) cnt
    FROM   action 
    GROUP  BY name) b
ON a.name =  b.name
```